# Video player selectable subtitles

Tags: media-player

I know there is PotPlayer that let you search for words, but what I'm looking for is a video player that let me select any sentence or phrase or word and copy it, PotPlayer just gonna copy one word at a time and won't let you select the sentence

this is an example of what I want (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oun2Q.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what OS should it run on, how much may it cost, what other features are essential. And btw your image link does not seem to work (I get an empty page).